# How to create better gradients in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient, linear-gradients

I am trying to create a gradient scale of percentages for a heat map. I have a few extreme examples - a vector of percentages like this.

```
x = c(100, 1, 2, 1.4, 0.5, -2, -90, 0.3, 2.3)
```

This means that when I attach a gradient - whether continuous or binned - it's almost impossible to tell the difference between the smaller percentage values. Is there a way to affect the gradient in order to make the difference between e.g. 1% and 2% more obvious?

Comment: You can use a transformation. Log tranformations are common, and they squish large values closer together while adding space between small values - but they only work for positive data. For data with mixed sign, a signed square root might be good. Essentially, use `x_ssqrt = sign(x) * sqrt(abs(x))` as the variable to color by. (Or, more robustly, define transformation objects [as explained here](https://andrewpwheeler.com/2015/07/31/custom-square-root-scale-with-negative-values-in-ggplot2-r/))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either choose colours close together on the scale with`scale_fill_gradientn`, or, if you want a generic solution without all that fiddling (and don't mind a non-isometric scale), the best separation you can achieve is simply to use `rank` as a transformation.

To show this clearly, let's make a raster using the example you supplied:

```r
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

z <- c(100, 1, 2, 1.4, 0.5, -2, -90, 0.3, 2.3)

set.seed(69)
df$z <- sample(z, 100, replace = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

We can only see 3 distinct fills despite our 9 different levels.

Compare this to:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = rank(z))) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(breaks = quantile(rank(df$z)),
                       labels = quantile(df$z),
                       name = "z")
```

[image]

This gives a smooth gradient bar but strange labels. You can do the opposite (have normal labels but a jumpy colour bar) like this:

```r
scale_fill_viridis_opt <- function(x)
{
  x <- sort(unique(x))
  x <- (x[-1] + x[-length(x)])/2
  y <- (x - min(x))/diff(range(x))
  scale_fill_gradientn(values = y, colours = viridis::viridis(length(x)))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_raster() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_opt(df$z)
```

[image]

Or, if you want to try a transformation to prevent these problems, you could try a signed nth root, where you can tweak n to suit your data. Your labels and colours are then nicely spaced, but the labels have less physical meaning. Here, we get a reasonable balance with a signed cube root:

```r
signed_nth_root <- function(x, n = 2) {
  sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/n)
}

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = signed_nth_root(z, 3))) + 
  geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>